# Make my app available as an option in the file picker dialog

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

How can i make my app available in the "Open From" dialog of the file picker? and how do i handle that request in the activity code?

Here is a screenshot of the dialog where i want my app to appear as an option(This dialog is from while uploading a file to google drive):

[image]

Comment: try intent-filter where as Some applications may specify the application to open, and some applications have already set the default applications to Open

Answer (score 1):

You can specify mimeType in intent-filter in your mainfest file.
your app will be added to share list.

For example you need to add your app for text share then use
**mimeType="text/plain"**

```
  <activity android:name="ShareActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Handle share :

Write this code in onCreate method of your activity (Activity which is declared in mainfest with intent filter(above))

```
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(intent.getAction()))
    {
        Uri uri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);

       //here you will get data which is shared.
    }
```

Comment: something like this :        if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(intent.getAction()))
        {
            Uri uri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);

          //here you will get data which is share to your app
        }

Comment: But how would i return the data(in this case, the file)?

Comment: i think you misunderstood my question.What i want is that when an app asks the user to select a file, i want to make my app appear in the chooser. The user will then choose a file through my app and that file will be returned to the app that called my app. So, my question is, how do i return the selected file back to the calling app?

Comment: use above code and try to share any file from your device,your will see your app in share list,....just select your app from share dialog.......and then you will get uri of that file....in on create of activity in above code..

Comment: ok ok got it.........    Try this IntentFilter:

<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="application/pdf" />
</intent-filter>

Comment: use mimeType according to your need..!

Comment: use this to handle it -> if (getIntent().getCategories().contains("android.intent.category.BROWSABLE")){...}

Answer (score 0):

I've faced same problem recently and solved it by handling this intent in my app:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
    </intent-filter>
```

[image]